# Accessing Windows environment variables in elisp

Tags: system-environment

I am looking for a way to access the value of `%HOMEPATH%` under Windows (or more generally, any environment variable of the form `%name%`).

The use case is to have a consistent `init.el` across multiple operating systems. In Linux and OS X, `(expand-file-name "~")` always gives the home folder, but the same command under Windows it returns `%HOMEPATH%/AppData/Roaming`.

Comment: Not on Windows right now, but I'd presume that `(getenv "HOMEPATH")` would work.

Comment: `(expand-file-name "~")` gives what Emacs considers to be the home folder, see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html

Comment: @npostavs Right, it's what what emacs treats as the home folder. 
Unfortunately, the location `%HOMEPATH%/AppData/Roaming` is quite inconvenient since most other things (e.g. Documents, Dropbox, etc) are stored in `%HOMEPATH%`.

Comment: As explained in the manual, you can set `HOME` to change what Emacs considers to be the home folder.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my own question; the relevant command is

`(substitute-in-file-name "$HOMEPATH")`

More information can be found in the [official documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html#File-Name-Expansion).

(The solution provided by @legoscia above also works.)

Comment: The answer for the general question of how to access environment variables of the form %name% is to use `getenv`, as @legoscia suggested. The `substitute-in-file-name` function solves the more narrow problem of resolving variables in a file name. (Note that it also has special handling for paths that contain '//' or '/~'. I haven't checked but that /might/ be problematic on Windows if you happen to have a double slash in a path or variable? Windows ignores the double slash.)